# How to reference single element in a typedArray in a loop?

Tags: android, typed-arrays

i have a `typedArray` that contains icons i want to use in my listview.when I tried to reference elements contained in the typedArray in the for-loop `this.navDrawerIcons`as shown below, eclipse gives an error as if the typedArray should not be referenced like normal arrays.

how can I reference the typedArray element by element from a loop

**code**

```
    private void initViews() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.navDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    this.drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerListView);
    this.navDrawerOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    this.navDrawerIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    this.navDrawerOptionDescription =   
    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items_descriptions);

    this.navDrawerArrayList = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItemDesign>();
    setNavDrawerArrayList(this.navDrawerArrayList);

    for (int i = 0; i < this.navDrawerOptions.length; i++) {
        changeSingleOptionContents(this.navDrawerOptions[i], this.navDrawerIcons[i],   this.navDrawerOptionDescription[i],VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`obtainTypedArray` returns another `TypedArray`. You can't access elements inside it like regular arrays. So if your `R.array.nav_drawer_icons` is an array containing resource ids at each index, then use `this.navDrawerIcons.getResourceId(i, <some default resource you want to show if there is nothing at index i>)` or if you have an array of drawables(i.e., `@drawable\R.drawable.something`), use `this.navDrawerIcons.getDrawable(i)`.

Also, as a side note, remember to do `this.navDrawerIcons.recycle()` after the loop and don't access the typed array after that. Something else to think about, do you need to store those arrays and the typed array icons as class members? You only need to access them in that method scope, if you are not going to need them after creating the list, then you can change them to local variables instead of class members.

Answer (score 1):

use `this.navDrawerIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)` where `i` is the number of the element and `-1` is the default value returned if the image does not exist.